# how to create multitenant app for office 365 in windows azure AD

Tags: api, azure, office365

I need an application on Office 365 which authenticate user of my Active Directory as well as other Active Directory.

Example.

My Domain is "Sample.com"
I've added Office 365 Tenant to my AD.
Created the application manually. 
All users Like "Mike@sample.com","Harry@sample.com"
are authenticated using my created application on AD.
But if i insert any other Office365 ID Like "kumar@mysite.onmicrosoft.com" with there password.
It is showing the following error message...

"Application with identifier xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx was not found in the directory enukesoftware.onmicrosoft.com"

Please help i need to authenticate and connect different organizations users and need to perform Calendar Operations.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm able to authenticate the Multiple Organization users by setting For Multiple Organization option.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151789.aspx http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aadgraphteam/archive/2013/02/25/building-a-multi-tenant-application-with-windows-azure-active-directory-single-sign-on-graph-access-and-role-based-authorization.aspx https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet

Answer (score 1):

Shekhar,

It looks like you might have solved the problem by making your application multi-tenant, thus allowing users in other Azure AD tenants to consent to your application.  I would strongly recommend that you look at this github code samples (over the ones previously suggested):

1. https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet for sign in and
2. https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-WebApp-MultiTenant for sign in and access to Office365 APIs.  This is a multi tenant app that queries the user's contacts.  If you want to look at other calls to Office 365 APIs (like calendaring) then this single tenant app has some examples:  https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-APIs-Starter-Project-for-Windows

Hope this helps